# magento 2 : show all attributes even after filters applied in layered navigation

Tags: magento-2.1, multiple-select-layered

I'm using Magento-CE-2.1.7.and i want to use Layered Navigation.I have added an attribute from stores-->Product.
catalog input type: **Multiple select**
under manage options, I have added 4 Attributes (**Cup, Instant Large, Instant small & Regular**)
under Advanced Options 
Scope: **Global** 
Add to Column Options: **No**
Use in Filter Options: **Yes**
under Storefront **Prop** 
use in search: **no**
Comparable on Storefront: **no** 
Use in Layered Navigation: **Filterable(with results)**
Use in Search Results Layered Navigation: **Yes**

and assigned it to Attribute set also.and after that I have created a product and assigned attributes to them.Category is "IS Anchor =Yes"

Default Category (1851) 
 --Shop Here (0)
---Grocery (0) 
 ----Biscuits (2) 
   ----**Noodles (15)**

Category Display mode: **product only** 
is anchor: **Yes**

Layered Navigation shows on the product page.but when I click on an option it disappears.

[image: Before selecting an option] 
 
[image: after selecting an option]

I want the layered Navigation to stay visible with filter option like in **the First Image**.

Comment: Any solution to this??

Comment: may be it's help you:
https://www.manadev.com/layered-navigation-filters-multiple-select-magento-2

Comment: Hey do u got solution on this?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/152962)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/152962)

Comment: @maliN, did you get any solution for this?

Comment: Any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

This issue does not occurring with Magento default theme (Luma) . Are you using any third party theme or extending the default magento theme. I have tested this thing with Magento 2.1.6 and 2.1.7 version with luma theme.

Comment: no.i'm using the one with sample data which I have downloaded from magneto site.it occurs in this demo site also.http://magento2-demo.nexcess.net/ .when I go to women-->tops and select an option from category filter.it disappears from the navigation.